# Fibonacci Addition Identity for Fibonacci Numbers Separated by 3 Terms

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci Addition Identity states that: $F_{n}=F_{m}F_{n-m+1} + F_{m-1}F_{n-m}$.
This was useful in showing that:
$F_{i+k}=F_{k-2}F_{i+1} + F_{k-1}F_{i+2}$.
However, I would like to use this result to express the same for $F_{i}$ and $F_{i+3}$, where we can express $F_{i+k}$ in some linear combination of $F_{i}$ and $F_{i+3}$
Is there any way to do this? I haven't been able to make use of the typical Fibonacci substitutions to make any progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $F_i = F_{i+2} - F_{i+1}$ and $F_{i+3} = F_{i+1} + F_{i+2}$; we can solve these two equations to get $F_{i+1}, F_{i+2}$ in terms of $F_i, F_{i+3}$ instead. This gives us $F_{i+2} = \frac12(F_i + F_{i+3})$ and $F_{i+1} = \frac12(F_{i+3}-F_i)$.

Now substitute this into the identity you've already found:
\begin{align}
F_{i+k} &= F_{k-2}F_{i+1} + F_{k-1}F_{i+2} \\
    &= F_{k-2}\left(\frac{F_{i+3}-F_i}{2}\right) + F_{k-1} \left(\frac{F_i + F_{i+3}}{2}\right) \\
    &= \left(\frac{F_{k-1}-F_{k-2}}{2}\right)F_i + \left(\frac{F_{k-2} + F_{k-1}}{2}\right) F_{i+3} \\
    &= \frac12 F_{k-3} F_i + \frac12 F_k F_{i+3}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much! This really helped!